# What is the use of nesting one component into another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, tsx

I am new to typescript, trying to understand one syntax that i came across

```
  <PTable<OpsQL.IReportFile>
      data-test="Reporting"
      {...props}
    />
```

What is the use of OpsQL.IReportFile .Is it a constraint or something else.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PTable` is a generic component and `<OpsQL.IReportFile>` is the generic type argument passed to the component.